# Reverse words in a sentence in c++ using stack

Tags: c++, string, loops, stl, stack

**Input**

"the sky is blue"

**Expected Output**

"blue is sky the"

**My Output**

"blue is sky "

**I am unable to point out the error in the code.**

Here is the code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "the sky is blue";
    reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
    stack<char> t;
    for(int i = 0;i < s.length();i++){
        if(s[i] != ' '){
            t.push(s[i]);
        }
        else{
            while(!t.empty()){
                cout << t.top();
                t.pop();
            }
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `reverse` does not reverse each word.  You should have seen that if you debugged your code.

Comment: I know that.After reversing I am printing out the elements using a stack.

Comment: Which will reverse each word...

Comment: eulb si yks eht

Comment: Why not make this simple and use `std::istringstream` instead of writing a loop checking for a space?  This is really no more than a 5 line program, without all of the checking required for a space character.

Comment: This is the output after using reverse.After pushing them into a stack until I encounter a space,I print them while popping them out which gives: blue is sky

Comment: [Example of std::istringstream](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e74bb8b65a975d).  No need to check for spaces.  So before posting any answers and getting the "my teacher or book hasn't taught me this, so I can't use it", is this acceptable?

Comment: Unrelated: Watch out for the `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` combination. It can lead to some nearly incomprehensible errors. More on why here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice . Together you have the entire standard library in your global namespace. That's a lot of potential landmines to step on.

Comment: Thanks,@PaulMcKenzie ,Now implementing using istringstream

Comment: You don know there's a far more efficient in-place method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You push "eht" into the stack, but you don't start poping it, since the length of the string doesn't allow you to, since the for loop stops executing.

Pop it after the for loop, like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string s = "the sky is blue";
  reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
  stack<char> t;
  for(unsigned int i = 0;i < s.length();i++){
    if(s[i] != ' '){
      t.push(s[i]);
    }
    else {
      while(!t.empty()){
        cout << t.top();
        t.pop();
      }
      cout << " ";
   }
  }
  while(!t.empty()){
    cout << t.top();
    t.pop();
  }
}
```

Output:

> blue is sky the

Answer (score 0):

C++ program to reverse words in string using Stack data structure.

E.g. "my.name.is.vivek.mutha" gives the output as "mutha.vivek.is.name.my".

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s,s1;
    std::stack<std::string> st;
    int k=0;
    cin>>s;
    int l = s.length();
    vector<string> str;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='.'){
            str.push_back(s1);
            str.push_back(".");
            s1="";
        }
        else
            s1.append(s,i,1);
    }
    str.push_back(s1);
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
        st.push(str[i]);
    while(!st.empty()){
        cout<<st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
}
```